# jQuery .each loop not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to execute the following little bit of jQuery:

```
    var c = 1;
$("#bench-box .pid-switch").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', 'pidsarray['+c+']');
    c = c + 1;
});
```

If I type paste that into the firebug console and run it that way, it works perfectly. This tells me that the selector is finding what I want it to find, and that it is performing as I want.

However, if I call it as a function in my code, rather than through the console, it doesn't work. It doesn't cause an error, it just simply won't execute. The rest of the code following it in a list of functions I call one after the other continue to work fine.

I can't figure out why it works through the console and not otherwise. Here is how I call it in my code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    adjustPids();
});

function adjustPids() {
var c = 1;
$("#bench-box .pid-switch").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', 'pidsarray['+c+']');
    c = c + 1;
});    
}
```

Any thoughts?

EDITED:

The jQuery code above is wrapped in $(document).ready(function () as per normal. My bad for not mentioning that in my original question.

Comment: Is `c` supposed to reset to 1 every time `#button` is clicked?

Comment: Yes, it is. I should have made that clear.

Comment: When do you actually inspect `c`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code you posted as far as I can see, is there an error in the console? If you plan to debug than I suggest using Firefox with Firebug or Chrome (no plugin needed); press f12 to open developer tools and see the output in console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function() {
            console.log("ok, clicked");
            adjustPids();
        });

        function adjustPids() {
            var c = 1;
            console.log("adjustPids");
            $("#bench-box .pid-switch").each(function(){
               console.log("and this is",this);
               $(this).attr('name', 'pidsarray['+c+']');
                c = c + 1;
            });         
        };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="bench-box">
    <div class="pid-switch">hello</div>
    <div class="pid-switch">hello</div>
    <div class="pid-switch">hello</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. Everything is now working correctly. I just rewrote it and moved some things around. (I rewrote the exact same code though, I can't find any differences from before to now... very confusing).

So I'm not sure why it works, but I'm glad it does and I will be moving on to my next task.

Thanks for all of your help, regardless.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var c = 1;
$("#bench-box .pid-switch").each(function(i,elm){
    $(elm).attr('name', 'pidsarray['+c+']');
    c = c + 1;
});
```

Comment: I would assume this is the scope of what .each was called uppon so that would be the correct object. myObject.dosomething the this in dosomething would be myObject would it not?

Comment: $.each defines the scope as the key in the object. Eg: each Dom node